# Getting byte value from Database and convert it into string for showing it in text area

Tags: java

In my project, I have converted a string into byte in controller then saved it to database. Now I want to fetch that string to textarea from database. How can I convert that byte into string which was saved in database and what should I write in controller to do the conversion?

Answer (score 0):

```
String q = "Ab";  
byte[] b = q.getBytes();  
String s = new String(b);  
System.out.println(s);
```